# Is there a way to print all my Sharepoint lists as a batch

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, printing

In my SharePoint-environments are 46 Lists. I have to print them list by list. Is there a way f.e. an app for sharepoint that I can install to print all my lists as a batch. Or is there perhaps another way to do this?

P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an excel file to combine the lists which you want to print.

(If the data amount is huge, I would suggest you export the data by [PnP Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) first, then printing)

[image]

[image]